# cd command not working properly, can't get to desktop

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command

I am really new to Linux and Ubuntu 12.04. Even though I already have the regular Firefox, I'm trying to install Firefox from Mozilla's site. Since I (at least think) that I can't install through a GUI, I'm trying to install through the terminal using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/80593), however, every time I try to use the `cd` command, like, for example `cd home/myusername/desktop` , it returns with the phrase "No such file or directory."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should mention the root directory :

```
cd /home/yourusername/Desktop
```

Comment: But I wrote exactly that and still return me the same error.

Comment: i corrected it try it now

Comment: is it ok now mate ?

Comment: No. It returns me the same message

EDIT
Nevermind. I opened a new terminal and now it fixed. Thanks.

Comment: write the command you are using

Comment: I was writing cd /home/fio/Desktop but nevermind. I opened a new terminal and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Linux is case sensitive.
The folder created by Ubuntu is named "Desktop", not "desktop".

Just type:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

or

```
cd /ho[tab]myu[tab]De[tab]
```

(Just an example how to use tab for auto completion.)

Comment: I tried cd /homyuserDe. Same result. I tried "Desktop" instead of "desktop". Same error.

Comment: Sorry, i was using characters used by html. Changed to [] now.

Comment: Also, see https://superuser.com/questions/271530/make-bashs-tab-completion-case-insensitive to make Tab-completion case-insensitive.